# How Maven Provided scope interacts with Test scope

Tags: maven

My project has a dependency (`Provided Scope`), then If I run my project under `Test Scope` for unit tests, then how does Maven find this dependency it needs during unit testing?
Would Maven just use the one in local maven repository (if exists)?
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. The dependency can either have `provided` scope or `test` scope. Not both. You cannot run a project under a scope. Scopes belong to individual dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope):

> A dependency with this scope is added to the classpath used for compilation and test, but not the runtime classpath.

So yes, during test phase the dependency will need to be available (or will be downloaded) in your local Maven repo.

Comment: If they are in a modular environment aka `module-info.java` it might not be added to the classpath but the modulepath. This can lead to a bunch of problems and the maven doc should be updated on this. That being said I doubt this was @Bostonian problem.